# Can we redeclare a variable from one type to another (from int to String for example)?

Tags: java

I was just curious if we can do something like

```
int tmpVar;
tmpVar=myClass.getInt();
myClass.giveImput(tmpVar);

String tmpVar;  //<<--gives error "Variable 'tmpVar' already defined in this scope"
tmpVar=myClass.getString();
myClass.giveImput(tmpVar);
```

Obviously I used a new var name for string, but I was just curious and didn't find anything online if this is possible.

Ps I know the above examples can be shortened to

```
myClass.giveImput(myClass.getInt());myClass.giveImput(myClass.getString());
```

Comment: Not in the same method, no. You can do so if they have separate scopes, e.g. each is in a separate block. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Just curious, and yes once outside current block var will be like it never existed

Comment: `didn't find anything online if this is possible.` because it is not.

Comment: Usually when something is not possible in programming, it's done for a reason (be it laziness, less bugs, cost, improved performance, etc.) and usually that reason is not a secret (unless you are apple). Plus questions are what make the world go round.

Comment: Even if it were possible, I’d advice against it. Too much risk of confusion. The reader could easily mistake one variable for the other. Better find two different names for your variables so everyone can be sure which is which.

Comment: If the scope is different (e.g. if one is a class member and the other a method variable), you can, it is a very good source of bugs (especially if the types are compatible). It is called [Variable shadowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java is not possible for many reason. First of all because is a  **strongly typed**  programming language so you cannot change in any case the type of a variable. So you cannot assign a value to a variable different from the type of its declaration.

**EDIT**

But you can use variables with same name and different type declaration if they are not in the same scope. In this case they are two different variables allocated in different positions

Comment: What the OP is asking has nothing to do with java being "strongly typed" (whatever definition you put behind that word - I assume you refer to static type checking?). Java simply does not allow you to declare 2 variables with the same name. (You are not allowed to declare `int a; int a` either, even though both are ints.)

Comment: @njzk2  Please read the title:"Can we redeclare a variable from one type to another". So my response was only about static type checking. Ps I've modified my response

Comment: no. because not being able to "re-declare" is about verifying that a variable (of any type, does not matter) is already _declared_  in the same scope. Type checking is not involved in variable declaration. (only in the variable definition)

Comment: @njzk2 your comment is about "re-declaration" and what you say is right. My comment is about change a variable from "one type to another".

Comment: but that is not what the OP's question is about.

Answer (score 0):

Nope.

You need to use a different scope, whether that be a local variable in a function or property of an Object/Class or a Super Class.